# Discord.py How do I check which roles has a user in a certain Server from DM?

Tags: python, discord, bots, roles

I need bot which can detect the user's role in Direct Message. I was able to do it from the server chat, but i need it to be done in direct messages too.
My current code simplified:

````
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

role1 = 'ROLE_ID'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #only user with role1 is able to send the command
    if message.content.lower().startswith('can I?'):
        for r in message.author.roles:
            if str(r.id) in role1:
                await message.channel.send('Yes you can!')
                return

    #everyone is able to send the command $hello
    if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')

    
client.run('TOKEN')```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse a `Member` object with a `User` object. `User` has no role, as it is not related to a server as a `Member`.
What you can do is get that user's member to the desired server:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

role1_id = 000000000000000000000
guild1_id = 000000000000000000000

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('can I?'):
        if message.guild:
            member = ctx.author
        else:  # private message
            guild = client.get_guild(guild1_id)
            member = await guild.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)
        #  only user with role1 is able to send the command
        for r in member.roles:
            if r.id == role1_id:
                await message.channel.send('Yes you can!')
                return

    #everyone is able to send the command $hello
    if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')
```

Comment: love u, thanks a lot for your answer and clear explanation